# Adding hashtag to the internal link that leads to blog search page with tag filter search Sitecore SXA 1.9

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, solr, content-search, search-facet

The blog index page has all articles are listed and the filter based on tag that works with solr search.

The search results based on sxatags filter will get added on the blog index page when apply specific filter.

https://domain/global/blog

The filtered query comes with hash tag like below for filtering articles
https://domain/global/Blog#SxaTags=insurance

From the different page or component i need to link the search results with specific filter using Link for viewing more results for related articles search.

Is there anyway that we could add the hashtag to the link and not query string.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - you want to generate a link with hash in your custom component?

Comment: @DawidRutkowski I have lost track of this question. I have the different component with general link field and need to add the internal link with hash tag. For example the home loans is the page and from home loans page i need to go to blog search page via "View related articles" with the specific tag "Home loans" as hashtag to get the right search results. https://domain/global/Blog#SxaTags=Home loans would give me the right search results but how do it set the #tag to my blog page on general link field